# PHP imagecreatefromstring, compresses the image by 106%, Anyway to not compress image?

Tags: php, image, post, curl

**The problem:** I am sending a 1.5mb image as POST data and when I save it on the other side, I have only a 160kb image. Is there a way to not compress it so much?

**Setup:**

So I have a script that sends image over a post request by doing the following:

On the **sending** side i execute:

`image_file_get_contents($imageFile)` and then I send it through CURL.

the **receiving** side executes:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($_POST['images']);
```

Comment: What exactly is 160KB? imagecreatefromstring will return a pointer. You have to look for the function that saves the image, usually as JPEG.

Comment: Why are you bothering to turn it into an image resource instead of just writing it out?

Comment: Just use `file_get_contents` only.